# ON Duplicate Key for exact combination of multiple values

Tags: mysql, key, on-duplicate-key

Let's assume we have this table:

```
--------------------------
| x  |  y  |  z  |  data  |
---------------------------
| 3  |  53 |  24 |  hello |
---------------------------
```

-

Now I **only want to update** "data" in case there is the **exact** combination of **X, Y, Z**.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SET x=?,y=?,z=?,data=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=?
```

This obviously doesn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only add a composite unique key over the three fields x,y,z. the it works.

You can also use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (x,y,z,data) values (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=?;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
You could have been more clear for "composite unique key" but I found it quickly by searching.